# Ensuring that two column values are related in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, rdbms, sql-server-2017, check-constraints

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and was curious about how to constrain a specific relationship. I'm having a bit of trouble articulating so I'd prefer to share through an example.

Consider the following hypothetical database.

---

```
Customers
+---------------+
|  Id  |  Name  |
+---------------+
|  1   |  Sam   |
|  2   |  Jane  |
+---------------+
```

```
Addresses
+----------------------------------------+
|  Id  |  CustomerId  |  Address         |
+----------------------------------------+
|  1   |  1           |  105 Easy St     |
|  2   |  1           |  9 Gale Blvd     |
|  3   |  2           |  717 Fourth Ave  |
+------+--------------+------------------+
```

```
Orders
+-----------------------------------+
|  Id  |  CustomerId  |  AddressId  |
+-----------------------------------+
|  1   |  1           |  1          |
|  2   |  2           |  3          |
|  3   |  1           |  3          |  <--- Invalid Customer/Address Pair
+-----------------------------------+
```

---

Notice that the final `Order` links a customer to an address that isn't theirs. I'm looking for a way to prevent this.

<sup>(You may ask why I need the `CustomerId` in the `Orders` table at all. To be clear, I recognize that the `Address` already offers me the same information without the possibility of invalid pairs. However, I'd prefer to have an `Order` flattened such that I don't have to channel through an address to retrieve a customer.)</sup>

From the related reading I was able to find, it seems that one method may be to enable a `CHECK` constraint targeting a User-Defined Function. This User-Defined Function would be something like the following:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Addresses WHERE Id = Order.AddressId AND CustomerId = Order.CustomerId)
```

While I imagine this would work, given the somewhat "generality" of the articles I *was* able to find, I don't feel entirely confident that this is my best option.

An alternative might be to remove the `CustomerId` column from the `Addresses` table entirely, and instead add another table with `Id`, `CustomerId`, `AddressId`. The `Order` would then reference *this* `Id` instead. Again, I don't love the idea of having to channel through an auxiliary table to get a `Customer` or `Address`.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Or am I simply going about this all wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use relationships in your relational database? You seem to be trying really hard and spending a lot of effort just to not use the database the way it's intended. Databases are pretty efficient with this stuff these days.
As for the question, is there a reason you don't feel confident in that suggested approach? What do you think is wrong with it? Have you tried doing it and testing it?

Comment: I believe suggesting that I "don't want to use relationships in my relational database" is an unnecessary and inaccurate exaggeration. An order has an address and a customer. A customer has a collection of addresses. I believe that I'm enforcing a schema that represents the true nature of that relationship, not circumventing the "intended" use as you imply. The extent to which you normalize a database isn't as much a debate of correctness as it is preference. I don't like the suggested approach because I'm wary of the well-documented poor performance of scalar UDFs.

Comment: That said, I did mention that I may be going about this the wrong way. You mention that I'm misusing relationships and the intended nature of the database, but haven't offered a suggestion or statement that explains these claims. It would be appreciated if you could elaborate.

Comment: An order has an address. An address has a customer. That's your relationship. De-normalisation is a technique in the database design toolbag, but it should only be used for performance reasons, and there's no indication here that you're solving a performance problem, just that you don't want to do it (reasons why unclear). As I mentioned, databases are much more efficient than they used to be when techniques like de-normalisation were more common, and most performance issues can be solved by implementing appropriate indexes.

Comment: IMO - yes, you're going about it all wrong. I suggest you look at the MS sample databases to see how one normally handles such things. I also suggest you really think about the entities and the relationships among them. A customer often has many addresses - mailing, branch, hq, delivery, etc. Here is it not clear why you directly associate an address to an order. Such discussions are difficult to have in a forum such as this so this may be something you should do in person with others in similar situations.

Comment: You should also consider what happens (or what should happen) when an existing customer moves (or just changes their address - i.e., not physically moving). Does that affect all the existing orders for that customer?

Comment: And i'll add that Amazon let's me ship to any address - not just "my" address. OTOH perhaps your model is closer to something like DoorDash where you deliver to a physical address. The key here is understand the actual system you are attempting to model in your database.

Comment: @SMor *"A customer often has many addresses"* - Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I believe the database I've shown accurately represents that. For example, the customer `Sam` has two addresses.  *"Here is it not clear why you directly associate an address to an order."* - This is so that when an order is placed for Sam, we know which of his addresses to ship the items to. In regards to changing an address: **(1)** This is simplified. In my real database, this will not be an issue. **(2)** This isn't public-facing. It's a (for now) single-user order tracking system for a home based business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, however at the root it seems you are struggling with creating a foreign key constraint to something that is not a foreign key:

`Orders.CustomerId -> Addresses.CustomerId`

There is no simple built-in way to do this because it is normally not done. In ideal RDBMS practices you should strive to encapsulate data of specific types in their own tables *only*. In other words, try to avoid redundant data.

In the example case above the address ownership is redundant in both the address table and the orders table, because of this it is requiring additional checks to keep them synchronized. This can easily get out of hand with bigger datasets.

You mentioned:

> However, I'd prefer to have an Order flattened such that I don't have to channel through an address to retrieve a customer.

But that is why a relational database is relational. It does this so that distinct data can be kept distinct and referenced with relative IDs.

I think the best solution would be to simply drop this requirement.

In other words, just go with:

```
Customers
+---------------+
|  Id  |  Name  |
+---------------+
|  1   |  Sam   |
|  2   |  Jane  |
+---------------+
```

```
Addresses
+----------------------------------------+
|  Id  |  CustomerId  |  Address         |
+----------------------------------------+
|  1   |  1           |  105 Easy St     |
|  2   |  1           |  9 Gale Blvd     |
|  3   |  2           |  717 Fourth Ave  |
+------+--------------+------------------+
```

```
Orders
+--------------------+
|  Id  |  AddressId  |
+--------------------+
|  1   |  1          |
|  2   |  3          |
|  3   |  3          |  <--- Valid Order/Address Pair
+--------------------+
```

---

With that said, to accomplish your purpose exactly, you do have **views** available for this kind of thing:

```
create view CustomerOrders
as

select  o.Id OrderId,
        a.CustomerId,
        o.AddressId
from    Orders
join    Addresses a on a.Id = o.AddressId
```

I know this is a pretty trivial use-case for a view but I wanted to put in a plug for it because they are often neglected and come in handy with organizing big data sets. Using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` they can also be indexed for performance.

Comment: Hey Geronimo. I appreciate your answer and perhaps you're right. The redundancy of the data may prove more harm than good. If that's the case, I imagine I could mitigate this in code by massaging the data to represent the schema as I see fit. That is, having a buyer and address as direct descendants of an order. I'm going to leave this question "open" for a little while longer to hear out some more potential voices but will be sure to accept yours if it stands as the best answer. Thanks again. (I'd tried upvoting as well but it seems I don't have enough reputation for these to take effect.)

Comment: @Santi no problem. And as noted you have indexes for performance, but I should put in a plug for using a _view_ to accomplish exactly what you want. It can even be done with it's own indexes using `WITH SCHEMABINDING`.

Answer (score 1):

> You may ask why I need the `CustomerId` in the `Orders` table at all. To be clear, I recognize that the `Address` already offers me the same information without the possibility of invalid pairs. However, I'd prefer to have an `Order` flattened such that I don't have to channel through an address to retrieve a customer.

If you face performance problems, the first thing is to create or amend proper indexes. And DBMS are usually good at join operations (with proper indexes). But yes normalization can sometimes help in performance tuning. But it should be a last resort. And if that route is taken, one should really know what one is doing and be very careful not to damage more at the end of a day, that one has gained. I have doubts, that you're out of options here and really need to go that path. You're likely barking up the wrong tree. Therefore I recommend you take the "normal", "sane" way and just drop `customerid` in `orders` and create proper indexes.

But if you really insist, you can try to make `(id, customerid)` a key in `addresses` (with a unique constraint) and then create a foreign key based on that.

```
ALTER TABLE addresses
            ADD UNIQUE (id,
                        customerid);

ALTER TABLE orders
            ADD FOREIGN KEY (addressid,
                             customerid)
                            REFERENCES addresses
                                       (id,
                                        customerid);
```

Comment: Thanks! I sincerely appreciate you including some code to achieve this as well. That said, I think you and Geronimo have convinced me that it's just not the proper way to do things. To be clear, my normalization concerns weren't entirely based on efficiency, moreso that a direct link from an `Order` to its `Customer` seemed to be a better representation of the true relationship, but the efficiency comments  were helpful nonetheless.